# Numerical integration in python with variable limits

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration, quad

I'm trying to numerically calculate the following integral:

[image]

The exact form of the functions doesn't matter.

I'm struggling with the innermost integral where the limits are variables of the outer integrals. I want to use sophisticated libraries like SciPy to do this, but its functions like `quad`, `dblquad` require numerical limits. Can someone help me with this?

I tried doing it manually by running `for` loops for every variable, but the precision is not great.

Comment: Please double check the documentation. `dblquad`, for instance, accepts callables for the limits of integration of one of the variables. There is an example in the documentation (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.dblquad.html). If that was not what you're referring to, please clarify.

Comment: I know you said the exact form doesn't matter, but to be able to help you we need something to integrate. Also, the notation you have is a but confusing since the du, dx, and dy appear to be before the integrand making it unclear what is nested in what.

Comment: I would evaluate the last integral as `B(u+x)-B(x)` and use interpolation from a numerically computed function table for the integral of `b`. Cumulative integration functions exist in `cumsum, cumtrap`, I do not know about `cumquad`.

Comment: Browsing the `dblquad` docs, I see there's a `tplquad`, which may make your `u,x,y` integral easier.